# Rearrange z-index

Tags: jquery, css, position, z-index

i have div's that arrange like this:

```
<div id='div1' style='z-index:50'>1<div>
<div id='div2' style='z-index:200'>2<div>
<div id='div3' style='z-index:60'>3<div>
<div id='div4' style='z-index:100'>4<div>
```

i am taring to  Rearrange  z-index with jquery  like this:

```
<div id='div1' style='z-index:1'>1<div>
<div id='div2' style='z-index:4'>2<div>
<div id='div3' style='z-index:2'>3<div>
<div id='div4' style='z-index:3'>4<div>
```

somebody have any idea  how can i do this

thank in adv
yoav

Comment: And what have you tried ?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to achieve. By the looks of it you are still showing div3 and div 4 sandwiched between 1 and 2

Comment: Why in first place aren't you setting relevant z-index then? Can't you set it server side? How this HTML is rendered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd do that by getting the elements, sorting the collection by z-index, and then iterate and use the index to set the new z-index. This does not affect the elements position in the DOM, we're only rearranging the collection.

```
$('[id^="div"]').sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.style.zIndex - b.style.zIndex;
}).css('z-index', function(i) {return i+1;});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/76YnN/)

Note that you have to close the DIV elements to make this work

Answer (score 0):

You can normally use jQuery's `.css();` function, but since your style is directly in the HTML it won't overwrite it. You can use `.attr()`:

For example:

```
$('#div1').attr('style','z-index:1');
```

You can do this 4 times if needed, and enter your own values.

Comment: `css()` override inline style, indeed, it's using inline style